# Flex with max height

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

How can I set a height of left column(block) to 100% using flex? I have dom like this:

```
<LeftPanel>
  <Logo />
  <Profile />
  <Chat />
  <SocialButtons />
</LeftPanel>
```

`LeftPanel` to have a height 100%. `Chat` should grow or shrink by free space, but it isn't. How I should use css(scss) flex for that?

Comment: what css have you used so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I got what you wanted to do, but if you want `<LeftPanel>` to be 100% of the screen and `<Chat>` to be vertically expansive, you should set its CSS with the following properties:

```css
.LeftPanel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

`<Logo>`,`<Profile>` and `<SocialButtons>` should have a defined `height`. Like the following example:

```css
.Logo {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

.Profile {
    height: 160px;
    width: 100%;
}

.SocialButtons {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}`
```

An then, here's two possible tricks:

```css
.Chat {
    flex-grow: 1;
}`
```

With `flex-grow` you can set the expansive factor of an flex item over the others, read the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).

```css
.Chat {
    height: 100vh;
}`
```

If `.Chat`'s parent doesn't wrap its content with `flex-wrap`, the `.Chat` will occupy the remaining space, of the parent's space.

Comment: How it works? .Chat with height: 100vh it's 100% of viewport height but in my case it just all free space. It's resolve, but I can't understand it

Comment: When you wrap child elements with a flex element, it automatically makes the child a "flexible element" so it get some default properties from the flexbox behavior.

If you want to know more, I'd recommend you to read these docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#The_flex_container